# Calculate the angle between two edges using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

Calculate the angle between two edges using geometry nodes.

How can I calculate the angle between two edges using geometry nodes.

[image: img1]

When I try and calculate it, it says 90 degrees (`see red arrow which is not correct`)  what am I missing?

[image: img2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `Sample Index` node samples an edge with index `1` — the second edge (`0` being the first). But mesh line with 2 points only has 1 edge, so the output of this node is a null vector.

[image]

Changing the `Sample Index` to `0` will fix the issue

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think Sergey Kritskiy [has answered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/290561/35559) why your group isn't working, and adjusted accordingly.

If it helps, this is a group using the same method as yours, with a little more generality.

- Curves don't branch, and have a vertex index order imposed, so the
  mesh is converted for calculation.
- The minimum swept angle between incoming and outgoing edge-directions is returned on each vertex, marked positive anticlockwise, with respect to a given 'Up' viewing direction.

[image]

It takes the *Arccosine* of the dot-product of the normalized directions, and derives the sign of the angle from the alignment of their cross-product with 'Up'. The cross-product is 0-length at  end-points, so 0° is returned for those.

[image]