Select corners of a line geometry node Blender
How can I Select corners of a line using geometry node ?


You need to calculate the angles between the 2 connecting edges of vertices like here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/290546/calculate-the-angle-between-two-edges-using-geometry-nodes

I assume you want to do this on more complex geometry than this example? Because this looks like there are no vertices inbetween the corners, so you would only have to select all except for the start and end point...?

No, there are vertices in between the corners

For each vertex read 1st and 2nd connected edge's direction. Compare the directions. You're looking for $90°$ angle between them:


